# Getting object instead of results, am I doing something wrong?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have the following code which should return an array of personnel, but it keeps returning the client object. I followed the documentation. I have checked that the data exist using mongo shell. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Mongodb: 2.4.9

MongoClient: 1.1

PHP: 7.0

```
$collection = (new MongoDB\Client)->intranet->personnel;
$personnel = $collection->find([]);
var_dump($personnel);
```

This is the result I'm getting

```
object(MongoDB\Driver\Cursor)#161 (9) {
  ["database"]=>
  string(8) "intranet"
  ["collection"]=>
  string(9) "personnel"
  ["query"]=>
  object(MongoDB\Driver\Query)#160 (3) {
    ["filter"]=>
    object(stdClass)#145 (0) {
    }
    ["options"]=>
    object(stdClass)#162 (0) {
    }enter code here
    ["readConcern"]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["command"]=>
  NULL
  ["readPreference"]=>
  object(MongoDB\Driver\ReadPreference)#143 (1) {
    ["mode"]=>
    string(7) "primary"
  }
  ["isDead"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["currentIndex"]=>
  int(0)
  ["currentDocument"]=>
  NULL
  ["server"]=>
  object(MongoDB\Driver\Server)#146 (10) {
    ["host"]=>
    string(9) "127.0.0.1"
    ["port"]=>
    int(27017)
    ["type"]=>
    int(1)
    ["is_primary"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["is_secondary"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["is_arbiter"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["is_hidden"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["is_passive"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["last_is_master"]=>
    array(5) {
      ["ismaster"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["maxBsonObjectSize"]=>
      int(16777216)
      ["maxMessageSizeBytes"]=>
      int(48000000)
      ["localTime"]=>
      object(MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime)#162 (1) {
        ["milliseconds"]=>
        string(13) "1501091758421"
      }
      ["ok"]=>
      float(1)
    }
    ["round_trip_time"]=>
    int(4)
  }
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.library.php

Comment: yeah that's what I'm following, as you can see i connect just fine and objects exist, just cant get results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the content of your `$personnel` variable is a `MongoCursor` object and NOT what you are expecting to be a result array. in order to retrieve values based on your query, you have to iterate each item on that `MongoCursor`.

e.g.

```
<?php

$collection = (new MongoDB\Client)->intranet->personnel;
$result = $collection->find();

$personnels = [];

foreach ($result as $personnel) {
    // do something to each document
    $personnels[] = $personnel;
}

var_dump($personnels);
```

or you can also use PHP's [`iterator_to_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocursor.php) function to convert it directly to array.

```
<?php

$collection = (new MongoDB\Client)->intranet->personnel;
$personnels = iterator_to_array($collection->find());
var_dump($personnels);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thank you so much.